# Magento 2.3.1 manage stock = no but showing only 0 left

Tags: magento2, stores, qty

I have turned on the feature in Magento that shows only x remaining when the stock is less than 5 which works fine.

However on products that are set to stock manage = no, it's showing there's only 0 left which isn't true as it's set to not stock manage.

I've found it's bringing it in because of this function $block->isMsgVisible() in module-catalog-inventory

When I look at that function it's simply doing the following

```
    public function isMsgVisible()
{
    return $this->getStockQty() > 0
        && $this->getStockQtyLeft() > 0
        && $this->getStockQtyLeft() <= $this->getThresholdQty();
}
```

Which doesn't take into consideration the fact it's set to stock manage = no.

How would I add in a check to see if it's stock manage = yes or no? I've tried a couple of things with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the description and linked code snipped it seems that this case was not accounted for during the development.

I've created a ticket for MSI to verify this behavior in different setups, fix it, and cover with manual / automated tests: https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2299

Comment: thanks @eugene I'll keep an eye on that ticket

Answer (score 0):

was you able to find the solution for this issue?
In my case we have MSI enabled & for products set with Manage-stock as false, its always showing product is OOS on PDP